# Python3 and elementium

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pycharm

I'm trying to refactor my tests from Python 2.7 to Python 3.5. On this moment I've got problem with elementium lib. What is wrong with this lib?

```
return SeElements(
    self.browser, context=self, fn=lambda context: [context.items[i]], config=self.config)
```

Error:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/elementium/drivers/se.py", line 96, in <lambda>
    self.browser, context=self, fn=lambda context: [context.items[i]],
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Line 96: https://github.com/actmd/elementium/blob/master/elementium/drivers/se.py

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are passing a value `i` to the `items` list. The error is pretty descriptive, it is complaining that the value of i is a string, not an integer. To access a list element by its index you must provide integer.

Can you share a bit of the code where you define `i`? Perhaps you just need to call int() function on it?